# Creating a Class to convert Centigrade to Fahrenheit and vice versa

Tags: c++

I've recently started programming in C++ in one of my high school classes. I'm currently learning about Classes and I'm having some trouble creating a class that will convert from Centigrade to Fahrenheit and Fahrenheit to Centigrade. I feel like I'm totally doing this wrong. Any help would be great. The program runs fine but doesn't convert, how do I go about grabbing the 'dCent' and 'dFahr'and using it inside my Convert class?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int nUserInput;
    double dCent, dFahr;
    cout << "Do you want to convert from Centigrade to Fahrenheit [1] or from Fahrenheit to Centigrade [2]" <<endl;
    cin >> nUserInput;

    if (nUserInput == 1) {
        cout << "Enter the Centigrade" <<endl;
        cin >> dCent;
    } else if (nUserInput == 2) {
        cout << "Enter the Fahrenheit" <<endl;
        cin >> dFahr;
    }

    Convert tempConverter;
    tempConverter.
}


class Convert {
public:
    void centToFahr() {
        //dCent = dCent * 9 / 5 + 32;
    }
    void fahrToCent() {
        //dCent = (dFahr - 32) * 5 / 9;
    }
};
```

Comment: A good start would be to  [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). When asking questions here it's helpful if you could *tell* us what's wrong with the code you show. Do you get build error? Crashes? Unexpected results? Or just don't know how to continue from a certain point? And of course to actually *ask* a question. :)

Comment: I know you are learning about classes, but for real code I'd probably rather create two [user defined literal](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/user_literal)s so I could just say `42_cent` or `107.6_fahr`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this :

```
    class Convert {
public:
    double centToFahr(double dCent) {
        return dCent * 9 / 5 + 32;
    }
    double fahrToCent(double dFahr) {
        return (dFahr - 32) * 5 / 9;
    }
};

int main() {
    int nUserInput;
    double dCent, dFahr;
    Convert tempConverter;
    cout << "Do you want to convert from Centigrade to Fahrenheit [1] or from Fahrenheit to Centigrade [2]" << endl;
    cin >> nUserInput;

    if (nUserInput == 1) {
        cout << "Enter the Centigrade" << endl;
        cin >> dCent;
        cout << "dFahr = " << tempConverter.centToFahr(dCent);
    }
    else if (nUserInput == 2) {
        cout << "Enter the Fahrenheit" << endl;
        cin >> dFahr;
        cout << "dCent = " << tempConverter.fahrToCent(dFahr);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> I'm having some trouble creating a class that will convert from Centigrade to Fahrenheit and Fahrenheit to Centigrade.

**Option 1**

1. You can store the temperature as a member variable.
2. Change the functions to return the value instead of using `void` return type.

---

```
class Convert
{
   public:
      Convert(double val) : val_(val) {}

      double centToFahr() {
         return (val_* 9 / 5 + 32);
      }

      double fahrToCent() {
         return (val_ - 32) * 5 / 9
      }

   private:
      double val_;
};
```

**Option 2**

The solution in **Option 1** suffers from the problem that `Convert` does not know whether the value it stores is in Centigrade or in Fahrenheit. If you call `centToFahr`, the value is treated to be in Centigrade. If you call `fahrToCent`, the value is treated to be in Fahrenheit.

You might be better off using no member variable at all and expect the temperature value as an argument.

```
class Convert
{
   public:

      // OK to assume val to be in Centigrade
      double centToFahr(double val) {
         return (val * 9 / 5 + 32);
      }

      // OK to assume val to be in Fahrenheit
      double fahrToCent(double val) {
         return (val - 32) * 5 / 9
      }
};
```